# Why is the collection of all infinite sequence coin tosses uncountable?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

**NOTE**: The question may appear unclear due to my very limited knowledge about the subject.

So I my instructor something along the lines that if we have collection of infinite sequence of coin tosses and assign a binary ${0.1}$ to Heads and Tails we can create a one to one correspondence between the collection of sequences and $[0,1]$ (which is uncountably infinite).

How is this possible? Since real line contains rational numbers, while here we are summing up rational numbers, how can we come up with one to one correspondence with irrational numbers? This is considering that rational numbers does not have the least upper bound property i.e. roughly there are certain numbers it can never reach, or there are gaps in rational numbers. How to prove that in this case no such gap exists in such infinite collections of binary strings?

Comment: Any number between $0$ and $1$ can be expanded as $\sum \frac  {a_n} {2^{n}}$ with $a_n=0$ or $1$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thats what I said in the question. But what is the explanation?

Comment: Because the sum is the first comment is not necessarily finite, it might be a series.

Comment: @nicomezi please. Point me to some resources, I am unable to understand the reasoning.

Comment: I do not know any particular document on this. Search for "binary expansion of decimals".

Comment: @nicomezi I have updated the question.

Comment: I deleted somme comments to keep the comment section clean, I invite you to do the same. Irrationnals numbers can be described by an infinite decimal representation. Suppose that we have a dice with 10 faces, each one labeled with a digit from 0 to 9. I hope you agree that we can represent any number between $0$ and $1$ by an infinite sequence of draws. Here with the coin it is the same, but instead of a representation with digits from $0$ to $9$ we use binary expansion.

Comment: @nicomezi now it makes much more sense. But I am still skeptical in the sense rational numbers also can be represented like that. So my first doubt how is sum of rational numbers resulting in irrational when rational numbers are ordered fields.

Comment: @DuttaA A sum of finitely many rational numbers is certainly rational. However a convergent sum of **infinitely** many rational numbers need not be rational. For example, consider $\pi = 3 + 0.1 + 0.04 + 0.001 + 0.0005 + 0.00009 + \ldots$. In other words $\pi = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n10^{-n}$ where $a_0=3$ and for $n>0$, $a_n$ is the $n$th digit of the decimal expansion of $\pi$ after the decimal point

Comment: Rationnal numbers can be described with an infinite sequence of tosses but at some point there will be the same sequence of finite length infinitely repeating itself . Which is not hapenning with irrationnals numbers.

Comment: @halrankard2 so I understand that. But like I said according to the Least upper bound property (which doesn't hold for rationals) even if we add infinitely many such small numbers we won't reache certain numbers. So how is this theorem not applicable here?

Comment: Also (this might be less related), here is a possibly a more convincing argument that the set of such sequences of $0$ and $1$ is uncountable. Consider the bijection between the set of such sequences and the powerset of $\mathbb{N}$ where a sequence $(a_n)$ is sent to the set $\{n:a_n=1\}$.

Comment: Also I will be grateful if someone provides some resources with a formal proof.

Comment: @DuttaA There is no theorem that says "Since the rationals do not have the least upper bound property, it follows that there is an irrational number that cannot be written as an infinite sum of rationals."

Comment: @halrankard2 but when we show that LUBP doesn't hold for rationals, essentially what we do is keep on adding small rational numbers and then claim we don't reach a certain number.

Comment: LUBP failing for the rationals just says that a nonempty set of rationals with an upper bound doesn't necessarily have a least upper bound *in the rationals*, but such a set *does* have least upper bound in the set of real numbers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/114008/discussion-between-duttaa-and-halrankard2).

Comment: @DuttaA You can also apply Cantors diagonal method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S=\big\{(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty:a_n\in\{0,1\}\big\}$ be the set of infinite sequences of coin tosses (so for example assign $0$ and $1$ to "heads" and "tails")

**Claim 1:** If $X$ is a countable subset of $S$ then $S\backslash X$ is nonempty.

> **Proof:** Suppose $X\subseteq S$ is countable. We may clearly assume $X$ is infinite. So enumerate $X=\{s_1,s_2,s_3,\ldots\}$. Say $s_i=(a_{i,n})_{n=1}^\infty$ where $a_{i,n}\in\{0,1\}$. Define a sequence $s=(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ so that $a_n=0$ if and only if $a_{n,n}=1$. Then $s\neq s_i$ for any $i$, since $s$ and $s_i$ disagree at coordinate $i$. So $s\in S\backslash X$.

It follows immediately that $S$ is uncountable. As your instructor says, $S$ has the same cardinality as $[0,1]$. As you've already seen from the extensive discussion, this is usually done explicitly using a bijection between sequences in $S$ and binary representations of real numbers. But, in addition to your qualms about sums of rationals, there are some annoying technicalities having to do with uniqueness of binary representations. So let me first warmup with a different identification of the exact cardinality of $S$.

Let $P(\mathbb{N})$ denote the set of all subsets of $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$.

**Claim 2:** $S$ has the same cardinality as $P(\mathbb{N})$.

> **Proof:** Define a function $f:S\to P(\mathbb{N})$ such that, if $s=(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is in $S$, then $f(s)$ is the set $\{n\in\mathbb{N}:a_n=1\}$. It is an elementary exercise that $f$ is one-to-one and onto.

Now it is a well-known fact that $P(\mathbb{N})$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$, which has the same cardinality as the interval $[0,1]$ (or $(0,1)$ or $[0,1)$ or any nontrivial interval of real numbers). A very detailed account can be found [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuum_equals_Cardinality_of_Power_Set_of_Naturals).  There are many such sources online.

> *Remark.* We can easily define a 1-1 function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $S$, which gives us another way to see that $S$ is uncountable. Enumerate the rationals $\mathbb{Q}=\{q_1,q_2,q_3,\ldots\}$. Given a real number $r$, define a sequence $s(r):=(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $a_n=1$ if and only if $r\leq q_n$. Then $r\mapsto s(r)$ is 1-1 since the rationals are dense.

In order to make an explicit 1-1 correspondence between $S$ and $[0,1]$, the most natural way is to use binary representations.

So let's do it. Given a sequence $s=(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$, define the real number
$$
r_s=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n2^{-n}.
$$
The sum on the right hand side converges to a well-defined number in $[0,1]$ (calculus exercise).

We now have a map from $S$ to $[0,1]$ sending $s$ to $r_s$. Unfortunately this map is not injective. For example $(0,1,1,1,1,\ldots)$ and $(1,0,0,0,0,\ldots)$ are both sent to $1/2$. So to fix this issue, we first focus on sequences that are not eventually constantly $1$.

Define $T$ to be the set of $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ in $S$ such that $a_n=0$ for arbitrarily large $n$.

**Lemma 3.** $s\mapsto r_s$ is a 1-1 correspondence between $T$ and $[0,1)$.

> **Proof.** Note that the only sequence sent to $1$ is $(1,1,1,1,\ldots)$ which is not in $T$. So $r_s\in [0,1)$ for all $s\in T$.
>
> Now suppose we have distinct sequences $s=(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ and $t=(b_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ in $T$. Let $N$ be minimal such that $a_N\neq b_N$. Without loss of generality, $a_N=0$ and $b_N=1$. Then we can write $r_s=u+\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty a_n2^{-n}$ and $r_t=u+2^{-N}+\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty b_n2^{-n}$ for some real number $u$. In particular $r_t\geq u+2^{-N}$. On the other hand $r_s<u+2^{-N}$ since $\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty a_n2^{-(n+1)}<2^{-N}$ (here we use the assumption that the coefficients $a_n$ in the last sum are not all $1$). So $r_s\neq r_t$, and we have shown that our map is 1-1.
>
> Finally we need to show that any real number in $[0,1)$ is of the form $r_s$ for some $s\in T$. So fix $r\in [0,1)$. Pick $a_1\in \{0,1\}$ such that $a_1=0$ if and only if $r<1/2$. Since $r<1$, we get $a_12^{-1}\leq r< 2^{-1}+a_12^{-1}$. Now suppose we have $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ such that
> $$
> \sum_{i=1}^n a_i2^{-i}\leq r< 2^{-n}+\sum_{i=1}^n a_i2^{-i}.
> $$
> Define $a_{n+1}\in\{0,1\}$ such that $a_{n+1}=0$ if and only if $r-\sum_{i=1}^n a_i2^{-i}<2^{-(n+1)}$. Then
> $$
> \sum_{i=1}^{n+1}a_i2^{-i}\leq r<2^{-(n+1)}+\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}a_i2^{-i}.
> $$
> This inductively constructs a sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ such that, for all $n\geq 1$, $\left|r-\sum_{i=1}^n a_i2^{-i}\right|<2^{-n}$. It follows that $r=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n 2^{-n}$.
>
> Now we only need to show that $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is in $T$. Suppose not. Then there is some $n\geq 1$ such that $a_{n}=0$ and $a_i=1$ for all $i> n$.  So
> $$
> r=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i2^{-i}+\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty 2^{-i}=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i2^{-i}+2^{n}
> $$
> Then $r-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i2^{-i}=2^{-n}$, which means we set $a_n=1$ in the construction above. This is a contradiction.

The previous lemma gets us well on our way to building the desired 1-1 correspondence between $S$ and $[0,1]$. However, we have a problem, which is that there are many sequences in $S$ that are not in $T$, but the map $s\mapsto r_s$ for $s\in T$ already uses up everything in $[0,1]$ except $1$. So we have to fiddle with the map a little bit. The main observation is:

**Claim 4.** $S\setminus T$ is countable.

> **Proof.** This is basically obvious. Any $s\in S\setminus T$ is completely determined by some finite initial segment, and so $S\setminus T$ is in 1-1 correspondence with the set of *finite* sequences of $0$’s and $1$’s.

So now lets start fiddling with the map. Let $Q=S\setminus T$, which is countable by Claim 4. In order to adjust $s\mapsto r_s$ to account for $Q$, we will just choose a countable subset of $[0,1]$ (namely, $\{\frac{1}{n}:n\geq 1\}$) and do a “Hilbert hotel” shift to make room for $Q$.

In particular, enumerate $Q=\{q_1,q_2,q_3,\ldots\}$. Define $f:S\to [0,1]$ such that
$$
f(s)=\begin{cases}
r_s & \text{if $r_s\not\in Q$ and $r_s\neq \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\geq 1$}\\
\frac{1}{2n} & \text{if $s\not\in Q$ and $r_s=\frac{1}{n}$}\\
\frac{1}{2n-1} & \text{if $s=q_n$}
\end{cases}
$$
Then $f$ is a 1-1 correspondence by construction.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I will go through it tomorrow and accept it if it is ok.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to provide feedback? It's a long post so I am happy to fix errors or clear up anything....

Comment: @DuttaA I have made some edits to the answer to make it more direct and not use Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein. From other discussions, I think your main skepticism has to do with why the map from the set of sequences to the interval $[0,1]$, which sends $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n2^{-n}$ is *onto*. This is part of the proof of Lemma 3.

Comment: I haven't had time to read the answer. But thanks again. I'll check it.

Comment: I will accept your answer but to be honest I do not have the real analysis background to decipher it. I will try to read your answer when I have the requisite backgorund.

Comment: Ok, understandable. Hopefully Claims 1 and 2 are more accessible and help with seeing why $S$ is uncountable and has the same cardinality as the powerset of $\mathbb{N}$. This cardinality is often denoted $2^{\aleph_0}$. The cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$ is often denoted $\mathfrak{c}$ (for "continuum"). Searching "cardinality of the continuum" should turn up lots of sources on why $\mathfrak{c}=2^{\aleph_0}$. But most of these will likely involve decimal or binary expansions of real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

There is a $1-1$ correspondence between the real numbers in the range $[0,1]$ and the infinite binary strings.

We just have to add "$0.$" before the infinite bit string to get a real number in this range in binary expansion and conversely , "$0.$" returns the corresponding string.

Since the set of real numbers in the range $[0,1]$ is uncountable, we are done.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer, but I have updated the question, maybe now it will be more clear?

Comment: I noticed , that strictly speaking it is not quite $1-1$ , there are in fact "more" strings than real numbers in the range, since $0.0\bar 1=0.1$ , hence the sequences $0111111\cdots $ and $10000000\cdots$ correspond with the same number.

Comment: But $1)$ this makes the set of strings even "larger" and $2)$ the additional strings correspond with terminating binary expansions and those are countable. So, at last , it makes no difference. Nevertheless, this should be mentioned.

Comment: To avoid this issue, you can take the irrational numbers in the range $[0,1]$ (still uncountable) which correspond to a sequence not ending with infinite many zeros or infinite many ones. If this subset is uncountable, then the whole set is it as well.

Comment: I understand it is difficult to explain in such forums the idea you are trying to convey. Can you point to.some resources where I can read your reasoning?